# How to send array of dictionaries with big data using afnetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, afnetworking-2

I have a big array of dictionaries with the data of trips. I want to send it in all one request but I want to get responses after each dictionary send. I using afnetworking 2.0 and use AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer.

Update. I use this method now, but if user get a lot of data there is a risk that it can be interrupted in case of bad internet. And i have to know what trips was been sent

```
- (void)sendTripData:(NSArray*)trips
    withSuccessBlock:(RequestSuccessBlockWithDict)successBlock
        failureBlock:(FailureBlock)failureBlock
{
NSString* path = @"add_trips";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"trips":trips,
                         @"mobile_id":[[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString]};

[self POST:path
parameters:params
   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLogLight(@"Full data trips send success");

     if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
     {
         NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*) responseObject;

         if ([dict[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"])
         {
             successBlock(responseObject);
         }
         else
         {
             failureBlock(nil);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         failureBlock(nil);
     }
 }
   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLogLight(@"Full data trips send failed");
     NSString* errorReason = nil;

     if (operation.response)
     {
         errorReason = error.localizedRecoverySuggestion;
     }

     failureBlock(errorReason);
 }];
```

}

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! please add some more details to your question in regards to what you have already tried, (including code) and why that did not work (including how the results differed from your expectation) so we may properly diagnose your question

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining). This isn't something that AFNetworking is necessarily going to help you with. The 'standard' model for HTTP requests is 1 request in, 1 response out. Optimizations like Keep-Alive and Pipelining exist, but will take more work to really take advantage of.